# How to get DDMS log? And It can't capture screenshot

Tags: android

I can't capture screenshot form my device with DDMS, then the screenshot dialog is show "Screen not available", [image]

and you can see the logcat show a message "screencap w:768, h:1024, f:1, size:3145728", so I think the screenshot was captured successful on my device.

Now I'm reading ddms screenshot source code, and the source code files are

/sdk/ddms/libs/ddmuilib/src/com/android/ddmuilib/ScreenShotDialog.java
/sdk/ddms/libs/ddmlib/src/com/android/ddmlib/AdbHelper.java

And I find AdbHelper.java class print many logs, but the ddms tool was running on PC. How can find this log message? Are there somebody have debug DDMS function? Or Are there somebody have the same problem DDMS capture screenshot failed?

Comment: make sure that your emulator is having the view of a particular activity

Comment: You could try to use adb to see the logcat message if you know how to install adb driver for your device. My coworker tells me that she couldn't capture the screen shot from DDMS due to the resolution of her device. Maybe you can try to use https://code.google.com/p/androidscreencast/ to capture the screen shot.